# Passing parameter via quertystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass 3 parameters to ashx file to handle the image, for that i used `ImageUrl=ImageHandler.ashx?uid=1&iid=1&pid=1` but the image get not bound..

Help with correct syntax..

Comment: Please show us the code you used in your ASHX file.

Comment: where the `imageHandler.ashx` located? Is it located in same folder where your aspx exist on which you put the ImageUrl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may forget `"` for the code plus the correct location:

```
ImageUrl="~/ProjectLocationPathToTheImage/ImageHandler.ashx?uid=1&iid=1&pid=1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ImageUrl=ImageHandler.ashx?uid=1&iid=1&pid=1` is a part of your URL, then it appears that `ImageUrl=ImageHandler.ashx` is a query string parameter. If so, you need to change `?uid=` to `&uid=`. What is the full URL that you are having issues with?